# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'instance' and 'instance' and __truediv__/__div__ differences?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am creating a class with a special method **div**. Here is my code:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self,r,a=0.0):
        self.r = r
        self.a = a

    def __div__(self,other):
        SR, SI, OR, OI = self.r, self.a, other.r, other.a
        s = float(OR**2 + OI**2)
        return C((SR*OR+SI*OI)/s,(SI*OR-SR*OI)/s)


    def __str__(self):
        return '(%g,%g)' % (self.r,self.a)
```

This is what I did:

```
>>> from classes import C
>>> u = C(2,-1)
>>> v = C(1)
>>> w = u/v
```

Then I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'instance' and 'instance'
```

However when I use:

```
def __truediv__(self,other):
    SR, SI, OR, OI = self.r, self.a, other.r, other.a
    s = float(OR**2 + OI**2)
    return C((SR*OR+SI*OI)/s,(SI*OR-SR*OI)/s)
```

I no longer receive the error. My questions are what does the error I got mean? What are the differences between using **truediv** and **div**? The version of Python I am using is 2.7.3. Thank you!

Comment: There is already a built-in [`complex`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#complex) type, do you really need to create your own?

Comment: Thank you I realize that. It is just for practice. I am new to python.

Comment: Your code works for me.

Comment: The version that came up says 2.7.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are on Python 3 or if you have used `from __future__ import division`, you will need to replace `__div__` with [`__truediv__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.__truediv__).

Comment: The `from __future__ import division` may be more applicable to OP, the Python 3 comment is just for completeness.

Comment: I can only accept one answer but this __truediv__ solution worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If you've done `from __future__ import division`, then the `/` operator calls `__truediv__` instead of `__div__`. Just overload `__truediv__` in addition to `__div__` and it should work.